# All updates (answers, comments etc) using stack exchange API

Tags: support, api

Is there anyway to get information about any change using the stack exchange API's? i.e. if someone leaves a comment or votes on an answer/question?
checking for answer changes is easy cause its a top level property, but the others seem to be a little deeper and require repeated requests to stack exchange from what I've seen.

e.g.
this will return a count of answers and a last_activity_date, however the last_activity_date doesn't seem to change if someone, say, finds an answer useful
/2.0/questions/ID?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow